# Quantile(X * k) = Quantile(X) * k?

Tags: random-variable, descriptive-statistics, quantiles

I just wanted to verify that this is true.

Say the .95th quantile of a random variable, $X$, is $q$. Then the .95th quantile of $\frac{X}{k}$ is $\frac{q}{k}$ where $k$ is a constant.

I am assuming this property holds.
$$
P(X*k > x) = P\left(X > x * \frac{1}{k}\right)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes, *if* $k>0$ because in that case, the two statements under the probability sign are *logically* equivalent, so they are really just two slightly different ways to describe the exact same underlying event.

Longer answer (assuming knowledge of some basic measure-theoretic probability definitions): Remember that probabilities are really functions over certain (i.e. measurable) sets. Thus, if $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a random variable on the measure space $\Omega$, a quantity denoted $P(X\times k > x)$ is really just syntactic sugar for a more pedantic statement like $P(\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega) \times k > x\})$. But now, note that if $k>0$,
$$P(X\times k > x) \equiv P(\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega) \times k > x\}) = P(\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega) > x / k\}) \equiv P(X>x/k)$$
The two outer equalities are *definitions* while the middle one follows by basic algebra showing that the conditions defining the respective sets are the same.

Comment: This is great! How do you say the statement $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ and $P(\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega) \times k > x\})$

Comment: I would probably read $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ as "$X$ is a function mapping $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$" and $P(\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\times k>x\})$ as "the probability that $\omega$ is such that $X(\omega)\times k > x$".